# how to communicate between threads with android OpenGL

Tags: java, android, multithreading, opengl-es

Suppose I get a stream of pixels buffer and I want to display them with `OpelnGL`; For that I use `GLES20.glTexImage2D`. Now I want to update the image each time I get a new buffer. How can I do that from the MainActivity or another class that is not aware of the OpenGL's thread ?

Here's my `loadTexture` method

```
private int loadTexture ()
    {
        int[] textureId = new int[1];
        buffer.clear(); // buffer is a public static variable
        buffer.put(data); // data has been created for the test
        buffer.position(0);

        GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureId, 0);
        GLES20.glBindTexture ( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId[0] );

        GLES20.glTexImage2D ( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGB, 512, 512, 0,
                GLES20.GL_RGB, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer );

        GLES20.glTexParameteri ( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR );
        GLES20.glTexParameteri ( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR );
        GLES20.glTexParameteri ( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        return textureId[0];
    }
```

Even if I add in the OpenGL thread this to the `onDrawFrame` method

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused)
    {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, mWidth, mHeight);
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgramObject);
        ...

        // Bind the base map
        GLES20.glActiveTexture ( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0 );
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mBaseMapTexId);

        // Set the base map sampler to texture unit to 0
        GLES20.glUniform1i(mBaseMapLoc, 0);

        // Bind the light map
        GLES20.glActiveTexture ( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1 );
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mLightMapTexId);

        // Set the light map sampler to texture unit 1
        GLES20.glUniform1i(mLightMapLoc, 1);

        GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, mIndices);

        // For test purpose, I try to update the data in the buffer
        byte[] data = new byte[512*512*3];
        for ( int y = 0; y < 512; y++ )
            for ( int x = 0; x < 512; x++ )
            {
                int pixel = 200;
                data[(y * 512 + x) * 3 + 0] = (byte)((pixel >> 0) & 0xFF);
                data[(y * 512 + x) * 3 + 1] = (byte)((pixel >> 0) & 0xFF);
                data[(y * 512 + x) * 3 + 2] = (byte)((pixel >> 0) & 0xFF);
            }
        buffer.clear();
        buffer.put(data);
        buffer.position(0);          
    }
```

but the image is not updated. Even if I try to add to the end of the latter method this, that's do not work

```
GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mBaseMapTexId);
GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGB, 512, 512, 0,
                    GLES20.GL_RGB, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I do that from the MainActivity or another class that is not aware of the OpenGL's thread?

First up - let's correct some terminology. There is no such thing as "the OpenGL thread"; if you use that terminology it's just going to get very confusing very quickly.

What you have is a rendering context from your platform specific (e.g. EAGL on iOS, EGL on Android) rendering layer. Each rendering context can be active in exactly one thread at any point in time, BUT can move threads (e.g. via a call to `eglMakeCurrent` for the EGL platform layer), which is why thinking of an "OpenGL thread" is such a bad idea conceptually.

Binding a context to a thread will remove any existing context's binding, and unbind the new context from other threads. In addition to moving a thread around between threads, you can also have multiple different rendering contexts bound to multiple different threads running in parallel, and that is the important thing for this question.

Data sharing like you want is achieved by having multiple rendering contexts in the same share group (see the `share_context` parameter to `eglCreateContext` if you are using EGL, for example), bound to different threads. You can create a texture in one context, upload the data, and then the other context can bind it and use it. Synchronization (e.g. so the other thread knows when it is safe to use that texture binding) must be done via an application-level synchronization protocol - it's not provided by the API.

The rules around state synchronization between multiple contexts get a bit complicated (in summary it's usually lazy, and only synchronized when a context rebinds a resource), so I'd highly recommend reading Appendix C of the OpenGL ES 2.0 spec (or equivalent in the later ES versions - it hasn't changed).

Comment: thank you for your response. In fact I have an issue even being in the right context.  In the `onDrawFrame`, I try to change buffer variable but this does not update the texture, how can it be ?

Comment: Your "buffer" variable is local variable to your program; it's got nothing to do with the texture data used by the rendering API. The graphics driver takes a copy when you call `glTexImage2D`. If you want to modify the contents of the texture you need to update "buffer", then then call `glTexImage2D` again to change what the graphics stack sees.

Comment: thank you for your response. I tried to follow your recommandation. So I added at the bottom of the `onDrawFrame`, the following code `GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mBaseMapTexId);
        GLES20.glTexSubImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGB, 512, 512, 0,
                GLES20.GL_RGB, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bufer);` , where `mBaseMapTexId` is the texture ID set in the `loadTexture()` method but it did not work (knowing I of course updated `buffer` in the `onDrawFrame` method). Thanks for your help