# Is the UI thread of Android an OpenGL thread

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am reading an example code and find it creates OpenGL resource in the Activity's onResume() method.
Does this mean the UI thread is an OpenGL thread?

Thanks.

YL

Comment: Your terminology is a bit confusing, see the answer to [how to communicate between threads with android OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39521441/295004)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. Probably my question should be “Is the UI thread bound to a rendering context？”

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'bound', but the render thread is separate from the UI thread. See: [Drawn out: How Android renders (Google I/O '18)](https://youtu.be/zdQRIYOST64)

Comment: Let me check. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, android main Thread is an GL thread.

Android View support hardware accelerate, opengl make the hardware accelerate.

If you take a look at the source code, you will found canvas is using opengl API.

But do not do opengl calling on main thread, it will cause some strange bugs on certain devices.